# Sitewide Ajax failure with http status 200

Tags: 7, ajax

I'm not sure what's happened but I'm suddenly getting Ajax errors for every ajax call, site-wide. An example, from the views UI:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /admin/structure/views/view/about_slider/preview/block/ajax
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: =[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"bartik","theme_token":"LEKfczQQG6fjcOEWhHnOrh8H-CJ0ihsdmJrl4nOQuAU","css":{"modules\/contextual\/contextual.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views_slideshow\/contrib\/views_slideshow_cycle\/views_slideshow_cycle.css":1},"js":{"modules\/contextual\/contextual.js":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/jquery.cycle\/jquery.cycle.all.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views_slideshow\/contrib\/views_slideshow_cycle\/js\/views_slideshow_cycle.js":1}},"admin_menu":{"destination":"destination=admin\/structure\/views\/view\/about_slider\/preview\/block\/ajax","hash":"c67043301703a17ae56d13565b86913c","basePath":"\/admin_menu","replacements":{".admin-menu-users a":"1 \/ 1"},"margin_top":1},"viewsSlideshow":{"about_slider-block":{"methods":{"goToSlide":["viewsSlideshowPager","viewsSlideshowSlideCounter","viewsSlideshowCycle"],"nextSlide":["viewsSlideshowPager","viewsSlideshowSlideCounter","viewsSlideshowCycle"],"pause":["viewsSlideshowControls","viewsSlideshowCycle"],"play":["viewsSlideshowControls","viewsSlideshowCycle"],"previousSlide":["viewsSlideshowPager","viewsSlideshowSlideCounter","viewsSlideshowCycle"],"transitionBegin":["viewsSlideshowPager","viewsSlideshowSlideCounter"],"transitionEnd":[]},"paused":0}},"viewsSlideshowCycle":{"#vi...http:\/\/mtairy.toomodernmedia.com\/sites\/default\/files\/styles\/461x307\/public\/IMG_3936.JPG\" width=\"461\" height=\"307\" alt=\"\" \/\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e  \u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\n\u003c\/div\u003e\n\u003cdiv id=\"views_slideshow_cycle_div_about_slider-block_2\" class=\"views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row views_slideshow_cycle_slide views_slideshow_slide views-row-3 views_slideshow_cycle_hidden views-row-odd\"\u003e\n  \u003cdiv class=\"views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row-item views-row views-row-0 views-row-first views-row-odd\"\u003e\n    \n  \u003cdiv class=\"views-field views-field-body\"\u003e        \u003cdiv class=\"field-content\"\u003e\u003cp\u003eEvery season we organize age and skill based baseball leagues open to all children in the area.\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003c\/div\u003e  \u003c\/div\u003e  \n  \u003cdiv class=\"views-field views-field-field-image\"\u003e        \u003cdiv class=\"field-content\"\u003e\u003cimg typeof=\"foaf:Image\" src=\"http:\/\/mtairy.toomodernmedia.com\/sites\/default\/files\/styles\/461x307\/public\/IMG_4087.JPG\" width=\"461\" height=\"307\" alt=\"\" \/\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e  \u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\n\u003c\/div\u003e\n\u003c\/div\u003e\n\u003c\/div\u003e\n  \u003c\/div\u003e\n\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e    \u003c\/div\u003e\n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e","settings":null},{"command":"insert","method":"prepend","selector":null,"data":"","settings":null}]
```

It appears as if some values are being left null, and I'm thinking that could be a clue to the cause of the problem.

Jquery.js is being loaded.
I'm not getting any errors in the console.

Any help with debugging, heuristics, etc greatly appreciated.

Comment: Other Jquery on the site (Jquery sliders) are working fine. This is only affecting ajax. I feel like some resource isn't being loaded, but I don't have much of a clue what or why...

Comment: Which theme are you using is it a your_own ( custom ) theme or one of the default themes of drupal 7.

Comment: @dkiscool I've disabled my custom theme - the problem persists despite the theme (basic, bartik, my custom theme, etc)

Comment: Related: [Cannot edit my views.. I get a JSON string?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/73187/1908)

Answer (score -2):

Visit jquery update settings (intall, if it's missing) and set a different jquery version on "Alternate jQuery version for administrative pages" section.