# What could be causing this ajax error?

Tags: 7, ajax

I am getting an Ajax error when attempting to open a panel definition variant "summary" tab.  Sometimes ajax is working and sometimes it is failing.  This [same question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19052/sitewide-ajax-failure-with-http-status-200) was asked twice several hours ago but one version was closed without an answer and the other was deleted.  Does anyone have any suggestions about how to investigate or solve this?

Edit: The error is generated in panels on only some of the vertical option tabs such as summary and general, but not on the context, layout and content pages.

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /admin/structure/pages/ajax/operation/node_view/handlers/node_view_panel_context/settings
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: [{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"seven","theme_token":"pfhU4ZtN-CjUT9YtHcYnH7OvO_Rbbb45p-GczYg97v8","css":[],"js":{"misc\/textarea.js":1}},"nice_menus_options":{"delay":"800","speed":"slow"},"admin_menu":{"destination":"destination=admin\/structure\/pages\/ajax\/operation\/node_view\/handlers\/node_view_panel_context\/settings","hash":"2dd7a85b62aff52c002ef6882d5ec80b","basePath":"\/admin_menu","replacements":{".admin-menu-users a":"0 \/ 1"},"margin_top":1,"position_fixed":1,"toolbar":{"activeTrail":"\/admin\/structure"}},"CToolsModal":{"loadingText":"Loading...","closeText":"Close Window","closeImage":"\u003cimg typeof=\"foaf:Image\" src=\"http:\/\/CR-Hub:8082\/sites\/all\/modules\/ctools\/images\/icon-close-window.png\" alt=\"Close window\" title=\"Close window\" \/\u003e","throbber":"\u003cimg typeof=\"foaf:Image\" src=\"http:\/\/CR-Hub:8082\/sites\/all\/modules\/ctools\/images\/throbber.gif\" alt=\"Loading\" title=\"Loading...\" \/\u003e"}},"merge":true},{"command":"insert","method":"prepend","selector":"head","data":"\u003cscript type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/CR-Hub:8082\/misc\/textarea.js?v=7.10\"\u003e\u003c\/script\u003e\n","settings":null},{"command":"insert","method":"replaceWith","selector":"#page-manager-edit","data":"\u003cdiv id=\"page-manager-edit\"\u003e\n    \u003cdiv class=\"page-manager-wrapper\"\u003e\n          \u003cdiv class=\"primary-actions clearfix actions\"\u003e\n        \u003cul class=\"page-manager-operations Array\"\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-actions operation-first not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/actions\/disable\" id=\"page-manager-operation-disable\" class=\"page-manager-operation\" title=\"De-activate this page. The data will remain but the page will not be in use on your system.\"\u003eDisable\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-actions not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/actions\/add\" id=\"page-manager-operation-add\" class=\"page-manager-operation\" title=\"Add a new variant to this page.\"\u003eAdd variant\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-actions not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/actions\/import\" id=\"page-manager-operation-import\" class=\"page-manager-operation use-ajax\" title=\"Add a new variant to this page from code exported from another page.\"\u003eImport variant\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-actions operation-last not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/actions\/rearrange\" id=\"page-manager-operation-rearrange\" class=\"page-manager-operation\" title=\"Change the priority of the variants to ensure that the right one gets selected.\"\u003eReorder variants\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003c\/ul\u003e      \u003c\/div\u003e\n        \u003cdiv class=\"page-manager-tabs clearfix\"\u003e\n      \u003cdiv class=\"page-manager-edit-operations\"\u003e\n        \u003cdiv class=\"inside\"\u003e\n          \u003cul class=\"page-manager-operations Array\"\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-main operation-first not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/edit\/node_view\" id=\"page-manager-operation-summary\" class=\"page-manager-operation\" title=\"Get a summary of the information about this page.\"\u003eSummary\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-main operation-last not-changed active-group\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"page-manager-group-title\"\u003eVariants\u003c\/div\u003e\u003cul class=\"page-manager-operations Array\"\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers operation-first not-changed active-group\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"ctools-collapsible-container\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"ctools-collapsible-handle\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"page-manager-group-title\"\u003eMaterial Articles\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"ctools-collapsible-content\"\u003e\u003cul class=\"page-manager-operations Array\"\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers-node_view_panel_context operation-first not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/handlers\/node_view_panel_context\/summary\" id=\"page-manager-operation-summary\" class=\"page-manager-operation use-ajax\" title=\"Get a summary of the information about this variant.\"\u003eSummary\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers-node_view_panel_context not-changed active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/handlers\/node_view_panel_context\/settings\" id=\"page-manager-operation-settings\" class=\"page-manager-operation use-ajax\" title=\"Change general settings about this variant.\"\u003eGeneral\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers-node_view_panel_context not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/handlers\/node_view_panel_context\/criteria\" id=\"page-manager-operation-criteria\" class=\"page-manager-operation\" title=\"Control the criteria used to decide whether or not this variant is used.\"\u003eSelection rules\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers-node_view_panel_context not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/handlers\/node_view_panel_context\/context\" id=\"page-manager-operation-context\" class=\"page-manager-operation\" title=\"Add additional context objects to this variant that can be used by the content.\"\u003eContexts\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers-node_view_panel_context not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/handlers\/node_view_panel_context\/layout\" id=\"page-manager-operation-layout\" class=\"page-manager-operation\" title=\"Change the layout of this panel.\"\u003eLayout\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers-node_view_panel_context not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/handlers\/node_view_panel_context\/content\" id=\"page-manager-operation-content\" class=\"page-manager-operation\" title=\"Add content items and change their location with a drag and drop interface.\"\u003eContent\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers-node_view_panel_context operation-last not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/handlers\/node_view_panel_context\/preview\" id=\"page-manager-operation-preview\" class=\"page-manager-operation\" title=\"Get a preview of what this variant will look like.\"\u003ePreview\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003c\/ul\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"ctools-collapsible-container ctools-collapsed\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"ctools-collapsible-handle\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"page-manager-group-title\"\u003eStory authors\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"ctools-collapsible-content\"\u003e\u003cul class=\"page-manager-operations Array\"\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers-node_view_story_author_redirect operation-first not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/handlers\/node_view_story_author_redirect\/summary\" id=\"page-manager-operation-summary\" class=\"page-manager-operation use-ajax\" title=\"Get a summary of the information about this variant.\"\u003eSummary\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers-node_view_story_author_redirect not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/handlers\/node_view_story_author_redirect\/settings\" id=\"page-manager-operation-settings\" class=\"page-manager-operation use-ajax\" title=\"Change general settings about this variant.\"\u003eSettings\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers-node_view_story_author_redirect not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/handlers\/node_view_story_author_redirect\/criteria\" id=\"page-manager-operation-criteria\" class=\"page-manager-operation\" title=\"Control the criteria used to decide whether or not this variant is used.\"\u003eSelection rules\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers-node_view_story_author_redirect not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/handlers\/node_view_story_author_redirect\/context\" id=\"page-manager-operation-context\" class=\"page-manager-operation\" title=\"Add additional context objects to this variant that can be used by the content.\"\u003eContexts\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers-node_view_story_author_redirect operation-last not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"\/admin\/structure\/pages\/nojs\/operation\/node_view\/handlers\/node_view_story_author_redirect\/preview\" id=\"page-manager-operation-preview\" class=\"page-manager-operation\" title=\"Get a preview of what this variant will look like.\"\u003ePreview\u003c\/a\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003c\/ul\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e\u003c\/li\u003e\u003cli class=\"operations-handlers operation-last not-changed not-active\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"ctools-collapsible-container ctools-collapsed\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"ctools-collapsible-handle\"\u003e\u003cdiv class
```

Comment: I had a similar situation and it was enabled devel (http://drupal.org/project/devel) module that caused the ajax error within panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.  When the module Drupal for Firebug is disabled, the ajax error disappears.  I will report it to them.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's just a limitation of the StackEx message area or what, but your ResponseText is not valid JSON (not terminated) -- even taking into account that it turns invisible after "data": in this web page.

Other than that, I can't tell much without a live example.

Comment: +1 and thanks, This is my first exploration of ajax and reading its message is confusing.  I was also confused that the error came back as 200, which is an OK message (?)